# How to fail whole flink application if one job gets fail?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

There are two jobs running in flink shown in the below image, If one gets failed, I need to fail the whole flink application? How can I do it? Suppose job with parallelism:1 fails due to some exception, How to fail job with parallelism:4?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of how you should go about this depend a bit on the type of infrastructure you are using to run Flink, and how are submitting the jobs. But if you look at [ClusterClient](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/ClusterClient.html) and [JobClient](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/core/execution/JobClient.html) and associated classes, you should be able to find a way forward.

If you aren't already, you may want to take advantage of [application mode](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/#application-mode), which was added in Flink 1.11. This makes it possible for a single `main()` method to launch multiple jobs, and added `env.executeAsync()` for non-blocking job submission.

Comment: I am submitting job on the yarn cluster. Can you please specify how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there any way to terminate the Flink cluster?